# How to show the approximate location from the end user location to store?

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I have store pickup addresses and google API key. Now want to show the distance between user location and pickup address in miles.

First, how to get user current location and how to show the distance between user location and pickup address?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's location by using the [Geolocation feature of HTML 5](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation). The Geolocation feature will return coordinaters (LatLng) which you can use as one of the origin parameters for your [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix) request, with the store locations being the destination parameter.